# When I install docker on my Mac book, I get some trouble

Tags: boot2docker

Yesterday I installed boot2docker on my macbookpro and everything seems to works well. However when when I run "docker -d " it shows an error `this is a client-only binary - running the docker daemon is not supported`. While looking online for an answer it seems the docker binary needs to be recompiled but is it really the correct way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker containers only run on Linux. To make this work on OS X, the boot2docker package runs Docker containers in a linux virtual machine.

The only part that runs native on OS X is the client. Which is just that. A client that talks to the Docker daemon running in the Linux virtual machine.

So recompiling the docker daemon for OS X will not help. It will only run on Linux.